# How to run project from Terminal in Ionic + iPhone?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic-framework

```
MacBook-Pro:myApps naveenkumar$ ionic run  ios
Adding in default Ionic hooks
Running command: /Users/naveenkumar/Documents/ionic_work/myApps/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/naveenkumar/Documents/ionic_work/myApps
add to body class: platform-ios
Running command: /Users/naveenkumar/Documents/ionic_work/myApps/hooks/after_prepare/020_remove_sass_from_platforms.js /Users/naveenkumar/Documents/ionic_work/myApps
Running command: /Users/naveenkumar/Documents/ionic_work/myApps/platforms/ios/cordova/run 
Cordova needs ios-sim version 3.0.0 or greater, you have version 1.9.0
.
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /Users/naveenkumar/Documents/ionic_work/myApps/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
MacBook-Pro:myApps naveenkumar$
```

Hello, 
I am trying to run my project from terminal. I am getting the above error. But when I go to given iOS directory run my project from **Xcode** it works fine. That means, when I run from Xcode I am able to run emulator /simulator and check my output. But when I run from terminal I am not able to run my application. Could you please tell me how I will run my application from terminal?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem when I run with `--device` flag, but works ok when I run on simulator.

Answer (score 5):

This is the issue:

`Cordova needs ios-sim version 3.0.0 or greater, you have version 1.9.0`

Here is the solution:

`npm update -g ios-sim`

Comment: **Bingo**, that was it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you do not have ios-sim installed.
From the [ionic framework website](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/), you can see the following statement:

> Note: iOS development requires Mac OS X. iOS simulator through the Ionic CLI **requires the ios-sim** npm package, which can be installed with the command **sudo npm -g install ios-sim**.

All you need is to install ios-sim by running this command:

- sudo npm -g install ios-sim

Answer (score 0):

simctl was not found.
Check that you have Xcode 7.x installed:
    xcodebuild --versionCheck that you have Xcode 7.x selected:
    xcode-select --print-path